# cannot access session in OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use SessionCheck class to enter entire controller to verify user

```
public class SessionCheck : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            if (session != null && session["LoggedInUser"] == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                                { "Controller", "Login" },
                                { "Action", "Index" }
                                });

            }

        }

    }
```

if user not verified redirect to Login Controller
In Login Controller I fill this session attribute:

```
Session["LoggedInUser"] = user;
```

then redirect to Index/Home Controller 
In Home Controller:

```
[SessionCheck]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    { .... }
```

I debug code, and the Session["LoggedInUser"] In Login Controller action filled successfully,
then redirect to action Index in Home Controller, but when I am in  OnActionExecuting 
session["LoggedInUser"] value is null.
this error not found in my local PC and code works fine, 
but cause issue in windows server and session value gets null in OnActionExecuting 
I installed visual studio on server side to debug and the result as I explained. 
the IIS version on my PC (10.0.19041.320) 
IIS version on server (10.0.17763.1)
application used .Net Framework 4.8 
this issue appeared from some days until now 
before that the code was works fine 
why this issue caused ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.
issue caused by antivirus on server,
update reached antivirus about some days ago
when turn off antivirus issue solved.